# Custom Repository for Library Gradle in android

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I am creating Android library module in which I need to include a dependency which require authentication and hence its username and password I can't share with my sdk users.When I am setting custom url in my library build.gradle it is not looking for repository.
When I put custom repository url in project level gradle it works but it is not working.
Code sample:

Library Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://custom.bintray.com"
    }
    maven {
        url "http://custom.bintray.com"
        credentials {
            username 'asfsafasf'
            password 'asdasfsf'
        }
    }
}
dependencies{
    implementation <gradle path of library present in above custom repo>
}
```

When I am using my library gradle in my project it is not able to resolve repository

Comment: Did you try the answers in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/4541602/4779042 ?

Comment: It didn't has my problem.I don't want to share custom repo url to my sdk users